# How should ChangeLog files be used when dealing with a trunk and branches?

Tags: svn, merge, branch, changelog, trunk

I have a Subversion-based project that is of a fairly standard form, featuring a trunk directory, a branches directory and a tags directory for the usual purposes.

In the trunk is a file called ChangeLog. It contains entries that feature a time, a name with contact details and a list of changes. Whenever someone makes changes, that person adds an entry to the ChangeLog and uses that exact entry as the text of the commit message. A ChangeLog entry could look something like the following:

```
2015-04-27 L. Ron Hubbard <lrh@sern.ch>
    * add class Vector to tools.py
    * add example.root
```

My question is this: how should ChangeLogs be handled when dealing with branches? Should the entries of a branch ChangeLog be tagged with the branch name? Should a branch ChangeLog be updated at all? Should all changes made using a branch be listed in one entry when the branch is merged with the trunk? Should there even *be* a ChangeLog?

Answer (score 0):

1. Changelog, which only duplicates data from svn log is just wasted time and space
2. Trunk's changelog must contain only changes, existing in trunk - not merged branches must not be reflected in it
3. You *can* include all changed from merged branch as one record for mergeset or *can* maintain and merge (I'm afraid - by hand) branch's changelog into trunk

BTW, nice changelog without headache for any size of history you can to get automagically with `hg log --style changelog` (Mercurial+hgsubversion for SVN repos)